# Unable to run tlmgr

Tags: tlmgr

I would like to install latex packages using tlmgr on my Ubuntu. I try `sudo tlmgr install tools` but I get:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

How can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the debian version of texlive. Sadly they do not allow tlmgr to update or install packages. It was to be done via the debian apt system. Only the upstream texlive has a fully functional tlmgr. Install `apt-file`, then run `sudo apt-file update`, then you can find which Debian package provides `file.sty` via `apt-file search file.sty` and then install that debian package

Comment: OK, and how can I install for example \usepackage{multicol} ? Texstudio writes `File `fontawesome5.sty' not found. \usepackage` thanks

Comment: @vojtam same procedure search for that sty and install the debian package. If you have the space install `texlive-full` that installs them all.

Comment: Multicol is a base package that needs to be in every latex indtallation